# 5 custom post types to use same custom single template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 5 custom post types that I'd like to use for a particular custom single.php template (single-careers.php) rather than creating 5 separate single templates. Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: And what have you already done? Can you explain what exactly do you want?

Comment: how much post types do you have? You can redirect them to single.php and let the others go to their custom single-type.php page.

Comment: I have 5 custom post types within their own separate pages and they require a single template as they have the_permalink() function. I created a custom single.php template for one of the custom posts but then realised I will be replicating this template for the other 4 so I wondering if there was a way if they could all use the same single template?

Comment: @Pakspul - the single.php is already being used, is there a way of doing this without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way, unless you want to use single.php for it, and maybe move what you use single.php for somewhere else. You can read more about [teamplate hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) here.

If you just don't want to replicate the code, you can always make a single-POST_TYPE.php for each one, and have those include a common template with the [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) function.